# Can the perror example be improved?

Tags: c, bash, localization, command-line-interface

When should I use perror and when not?
I look at the [example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html) and I think the example could be better for instance there is nothing about localizing, what I can pass to perror or if I should use perror if I implement something like a command-line interpreter or some other C program..

Comment: You use `perror` when you want to know what went wrong if a call of a function that sets `errno` on failure failed. If `errno` isn't set, you don't use `perror` (Well, you can, but it adds an interpretation of an unrelated `errno` value, so `fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",oops_message);` is better then).

Comment: Thanks! But you don't say when not to use perror.

Comment: Second sentence, "If `errno` isn't set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of `perror` is that it produces standardised messages. For example, if you try to `fopen` a file that cannot be found, the message is *always* "No such file or directory". This makes the error message better understood (rather than having lots of programs producing different messages to say the same thing), but also it enables generic utilities to be used to search for error messages/types.

The only real reason not to use it is if the system or library call you've used doesn't set `errno`. If standard output is unavailable, you can still use `strerror` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> When should I use perror and when not?

Use perror when you want a description of the error corresponding to *errno* written to stderr.

> I look at the example and I think the example could be better for
>   instance there is nothing about localizing

The example is just fine. There is no locality for the argument; If you want locality there, you'll need to engineer your own; After all, it is *your programs* argument... If you read the description carefully, you'll notice a link to [strerror](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strerror.html). This page tells you how the locality of the error messages is handled by the implementation.

> what I can pass to perror

Actually, that page tells you exactly what to pass: "... the string pointed to by s...". A string is a sequence of characters that terminates at the first '\0'. Don't forget: "String literals" are silently converted to arrays, and when you pass an array to a function, that array is silently converted to a pointer.

> if I should use perror if a implement something olike a command-line
>   or some other C program.

stderr isn't exclusive to command-line development. Consider daemons: If you add a process as a daemon to your crontab, cron.d will send stderr to your email. Additionally, various GUI toolkits might *freopen* stderr so that error messages get written to *stderr.log* or something...

Comment: @NickRosencrantz There are an infinite number of answers to "When shouldn't I use ____?" questions. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: "I was wondering if I could use `perror` to wash my clothes. ;) Do you think that will be possible? ;)"...

Comment: Why doesn't this C program use perror http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/cat/cat.c Can it still output localized error messages?

Comment: People sometimes do strange things... Perhaps. Does your command line interface implement a translator?